# Error when updating Axis2 web services from version 1.5.6 to 1.6.3

Tags: web-services, apache-axis

I used to run my web services on Axis2 V1.5.6. But now I want to run them on Axis2 V1.6.3. 
On the 1.5.6 version, my services work well but when I try to use them on the 1.6.3 version, I get this error when I'm calling a method for the first time :

```
Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method getAllReferentiels
```

when I glance in my tomcat logs I can see that an exception is raised :

```
[ERROR] Exception occurred while trying to invoke service method getAllReferentiels
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:121)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.invokeAxisEngine(RESTUtil.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.processURLRequest(RESTUtil.java:139)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet$RestRequestProcessor.processURLRequest(AxisServlet.java:837)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:273)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.RenderedImageProvider.<clinit>(RenderedImageProvider.java:69)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper$3.run(ReflectionHelper.java:289)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper$3.run(ReflectionHelper.java:279)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder$AbstractLazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceFinder.java:697)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder.toClassArray(ServiceFinder.java:549)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServiceClasses(ProviderServices.java:345)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServiceClasses(ProviderServices.java:338)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServices(ProviderServices.java:162)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:176)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:162)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.init(Client.java:343)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.access$000(Client.java:119)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:192)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:188)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:188)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:160)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:673)
    at com.refComp.dao.utils.Neo4jUtil.getClient(Neo4jUtil.java:44)
    at com.refComp.dao.utils.Neo4jUtil.getNodesWithLabelInJSONArray(Neo4jUtil.java:140)
    at com.refComp.dao.utils.Neo4jUtil.getAllReferentiels(Neo4jUtil.java:411)
    at com.refComp.dao.services.impl.RefCompDAOServiceImpl.getAllReferentiels(RefCompDAOServiceImpl.java:43)
    at com.refComp.dao.services.RefCompDAOServiceUtil.getAllReferentiels(RefCompDAOServiceUtil.java:29)
    at com.refComp.services.impl.RefCompServiceImpl.getXMLReferentielsInString(RefCompServiceImpl.java:314)
    at com.refComp.services.RefCompServiceUtil.getXMLReferentielsInString(RefCompServiceUtil.java:57)
    at com.refComp.services.ws.ReferentielWS.getAllReferentiels(ReferentielWS.java:30)
    ... 36 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegateImpl
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:122)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:91)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType.<clinit>(MediaType.java:44)
    ... 65 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegateImpl
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1305)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1157)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.newInstance(FactoryFinder.java:62)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.FactoryFinder.find(FactoryFinder.java:155)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:105)
    ... 67 more
```

When I run the method for the second time, I get this error :

```
Could not initialize class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.RenderedImageProvider
```

And these logs :

```
[ERROR] Could not initialize class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.RenderedImageProvider
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCUtil.invokeServiceClass(RPCUtil.java:212)
    at org.apache.axis2.rpc.receivers.RPCMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(RPCMessageReceiver.java:121)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:114)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:181)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.invokeAxisEngine(RESTUtil.java:144)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.util.RESTUtil.processURLRequest(RESTUtil.java:139)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet$RestRequestProcessor.processURLRequest(AxisServlet.java:837)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.http.AxisServlet.doGet(AxisServlet.java:273)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:622)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:617)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:518)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1091)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:668)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1521)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1478)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.RenderedImageProvider
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper$3.run(ReflectionHelper.java:289)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.reflection.ReflectionHelper$3.run(ReflectionHelper.java:279)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder$AbstractLazyIterator.hasNext(ServiceFinder.java:697)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.service.ServiceFinder.toClassArray(ServiceFinder.java:549)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServiceClasses(ProviderServices.java:345)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServiceClasses(ProviderServices.java:338)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.component.ProviderServices.getServices(ProviderServices.java:162)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.initReaders(MessageBodyFactory.java:176)
    at com.sun.jersey.core.spi.factory.MessageBodyFactory.init(MessageBodyFactory.java:162)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.init(Client.java:343)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.access$000(Client.java:119)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:192)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client$1.f(Client.java:188)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:193)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:188)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.<init>(Client.java:160)
    at com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(Client.java:673)
    at com.refComp.dao.utils.Neo4jUtil.getClient(Neo4jUtil.java:44)
    at com.refComp.dao.utils.Neo4jUtil.getNodesWithLabelInJSONArray(Neo4jUtil.java:140)
    at com.refComp.dao.utils.Neo4jUtil.getAllReferentiels(Neo4jUtil.java:411)
    at com.refComp.dao.services.impl.RefCompDAOServiceImpl.getAllReferentiels(RefCompDAOServiceImpl.java:43)
    at com.refComp.dao.services.RefCompDAOServiceUtil.getAllReferentiels(RefCompDAOServiceUtil.java:29)
    at com.refComp.services.impl.RefCompServiceImpl.getXMLReferentielsInString(RefCompServiceImpl.java:314)
    at com.refComp.services.RefCompServiceUtil.getXMLReferentielsInString(RefCompServiceUtil.java:57)
    at com.refComp.services.ws.ReferentielWS.getAllReferentiels(ReferentielWS.java:30)
    ... 36 more
```

It seems that in both cases, the error is similar. When I use com.sun.jersey.api.client.Client.create(), something goes wrong and the class com.sun.jersey.core.impl.provider.entity.RenderedImageProvider could not be initialized. 
I don't know why this error happens. Maybe my archive .aar doesn't fit with the 1.6.3 version (because I use the same for both versions)
I hope someone can help me to understand..

thanks,

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Finally I made it working with adding jersey-bundle-1.19.jar into the lib directory of Axis2 (in webapps) and restart the tomcat.

Comment: Hi Tom,

Am getting compiler error, when migrating 1.5.6 to 1.6.3
"Description Resource Path Location Type
The project was not built since its build path is incomplete. Cannot find the class file for org.apache.axis2.databinding.utils.writer.MTOMAwareXMLStreamWriter. Fix the build path then try building this project xCaps  Unknown Java Problem "

                                             MTOMAwareXMLStreamWriter - class is not available in 1.6.3
what you done for this....

Am using the java class generated by the axis 1.5.6. Is it i need to gen. new class files by using 1.6.3