# Getting ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegateImpl after upgrading Axis2 library

Tags: java, jersey, apache-axis, classnotfoundexception

Recently we have upgraded axis2 library in our project. We have upgraded it to 1.7.9 from 1.6.2
and since then we are facing below issue.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.sun.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegateImpl
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.findDelegate(RuntimeDelegate.java:122)
    at javax.ws.rs.ext.RuntimeDelegate.getInstance(RuntimeDelegate.java:91)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.newInstance(UriBuilder.java:69)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:80)
    at javax.ws.rs.core.UriBuilder.fromUri(UriBuilder.java:99)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.<init>(JerseyWebTarget.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(JerseyClient.java:290)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyClient.target(JerseyClient.java:76)
    at com.xyz.MyClass.method1(MyClass.java:55)
```

As you can see our MyClass.method1() method call JerseyClient.target() which is in jersey-client library (Version 2.23.1) which internally
calls methods of  javax.ws.rs-api library ((Version 2.0.1).

RuntimeDelegate class of that library is trying to load RuntimeDelegateImpl at runtime
which is jersey-bundle. But I dont know how its related to Axis2 library. Could you please help me out finding the root cause of this issue ?

I have found similar issue in SO but actual root cause is not mentioned there.

Link : [Error when updating Axis2 web services from version 1.5.6 to 1.6.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31475316/error-when-updating-axis2-web-services-from-version-1-5-6-to-1-6-3)

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For maven project, addding below dependency fixed issue for me in the pom.xml file under dependencies.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.12</version>
     </dependency>
```